# Divide players in groups based on group-preferences of the players

Tags: python

I would like to use Python to divide n players in 6 groups, which can be of varying, but in advance determined size. For example, for 15 players: 3 groups of 3 players and 3 groups of 2 players. Each of the players can give their preference to certain groups in advance, in terms of a top 3:

```
PLAYER     PREF 1     PREF 2     PREF 3
player1    group 3    group 4    group 6
player2    group 1    group 5    group 3
player3    group 2    group 1    group 3
...        ...        ...        ...
```

It doesn't matter which players are together in a group. I would like to determine the 10 or 20 best combinations for which all players get their most preferred group possible. (The reason for this 10 or 20 is that there are other factors important as well, which will eliminate some combinations.)

Right now, I made some code which generates all possible combinations and scores them one by one based on the amount of players that get one of their preferences (pref 1 = 3pts, pref2 = 2pts, pref3 = 1pt). If at least one of the players does not get a group of their top 3, the general score of this combination is set to 0. Only the 10 combinations with the best score are kept. This method is good enough for a limited amount of players, but for n>15, calculations are taking a really long time. I know for sure that this is not the best method, but I have no idea what the best way would be to tackle this problem. (I was thinking of a method which only swaps 2 players of different groups and evaluates if this is a step forward or not, but I'm not sure how I should implement this.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your problem is a [stable marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) problem. You can use a stable matching algorithm (ex: Gale Shapley) for that.

Comment: Isn't this something different? I'm not trying to match the players with each other, I'm trying to match each player with a certain team. I already looked up the stable marriage problem and similar problems, but none seem to be similar to my problem.

Comment: think about players as husbands and preferences as wifes :)

Comment: match husband with wifes based on the preference order of the husbands

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I think it is not so straightforward. In the stable marriage problem both the husbands and the wifes would have preferences. In this case each player is equally suitable for each group. So only the players have preferences, but the groups don't. If 5 players 'propose' for the same group with a max amount of 4 players, there is no criterium for selecting the 4 most suitable players... Or is there something I'm not seeing here?